# Is it possible to rollback if the import of schema from database into HCL OneTest Data fails?

Tags: dataset, schema, importerror, rollback

When a user imports the schema or sample data set from the database then will the rollback happens if the database import fails?

Answer (score 0):

In HCL OneTest Data, the rollback happens only at the table level. For example, if the data insertion fails for a table then all the data will be rolled back.